# How to launch our installed app from google assistant using custom word

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions, google-assistant

I want to open my installed app from google Assistant using custom word.

**saying "OK Google, Open MYAPP** -> we don't need to do anything on your behalf. Google Assistant will open the app.

**saying "OK Google,  Some word (Hey MyAppName)** -> Now I want to open my installed app. It is possible using App Action / dialogflow ?

I have tried below code but not working for me

```
 <action intentName="custom.actions.intent.HEY_PRINTER" queryPatterns="@arrays/ExampleQueries1">
        <!-- Define parameters -->
        <!-- Define fulfillment -->
        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
            urlTemplate="https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/stats" />

    </action>

<string-array name="ExampleQueries">
    <item>Hey printer</item>
</string-array>
```

Expected:
**saying "OK Google,  Hey Printer** -> I want to trigger "custom.actions.intent.HEY_PRINTER" So that my app will be open.

Can anyone suggest for this

Comment: Your string array is called "ExampleQueries", but your actions.xml references something different called "ExampleQueries1".

Comment: are you able to it, I am also struggling with such a solution, if you are able to do it kindly post your full solution

Comment: @ZubairAkber We can't able to launch the app using custom word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that doesn't work. According to the official docs:

> When providing query patterns for custom intents, expect each pattern
> to follow an explicit invocation like "open ExampleApp and" or "start
> ExampleApp and". For example, consider the following user queries:

> - "Hey Google, open ExampleGameApp and start making a cake."
> - "Hey Google, open ExampleGameApp and start making an apple pie."
> - "Hey Google, start ExampleGameApp and craft 5 cake items."
> - "Hey Google, use ExampleGameApp to produce cake 5 times."

Answer (score 0):

There is a Simple Way for Connecting Google to Outside World and Making it configurable according to You:

1. To Your Question, The Answer is **Assistant Settings>Routines** and set Command and in response choose app. In Response, You can choose multiple actions also but this method won't work with Outside world like Iot programs.
2. For IoT programs and Outside Google Programs, You need to connect Google Assistant to IFTTT or Zapier or Similar Response Services which enable Webhooks and much more to control over.